# Find Matrix of Covariances

Tags: regression, linear-model

Given the linear model $y=X\beta + \epsilon$ and that the residual,r, is defined as $r = y-\hat y = y-X\beta $, Find the matrix of Covariances Cov(r,y).

I know that generally $Cov(X, Y ) = E[(X − µx )(Y − µy )] = E[XY ] − µxµy$, but unsure how to apply that to this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The covariance between residuals and predictor variable $\hat{Y}$ is zero for a linear regression model.

From a linear model $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$, we can use normal equation to to calculate the Hat matrix $H=X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^T$, so we can have the fitted value $\hat{Y}=HY$, then the residual $e=Y-\hat{Y}=(1-H)Y$. Since $H$ is idempotent, i.e. $H^2=H$, then use your formula $Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-\mu_x\mu_y$.

The second term should be zero, since the mean of the residual should be zero.

The we need to calculate $E[\hat{Y}^{T}e]$, but we know that $$\hat{Y}^{T}e=Y^TH(1-H)Y=Y^T(H-H^2)Y=Y^T(H-H)Y=0$$